# Formatting String to a Date with Hours and Minutes

Tags: r, date, dplyr

I obtained a time string looking like this: 
`201902041502, containing year, month, day, hour and minute`.
Now I want to reformat this string into the german date-time format like this: `04.02.2019 15:02.`

I've already tried `as.Date` and `as.POSIXct` but it doesnt work and I want to avoid adding seconds to get `POSIXct` to work.

Thanks in advance! Cheers

Comment: Did you try this? `strftime(as.POSIXct('201902041502',format='%Y%m%d%H%M'), format='%d.%m.%Y %H:%M')`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `strptime` to convert the data to a POSIXlt object,

```
x <- "201902041502"
xd <- strptime(x,"%Y%m%d%H%M")
# [1] "2019-02-04 15:02:00 CET"
```

and then use `strftime` to produce your desired format:

```
strftime(xd, "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M")
# [1] "04.02.2019 15:02"
```